# Reactive Banana: Change status in data

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

Starting from the Counter example in Reactive Banana Wx that uses a normal `Int` to keep the counter status:

```hs
let networkDescription :: forall t. Frameworks t => Moment t () 
    networkDescription = do
    eup   <- event0 bup   command
    edown <- event0 bdown command

    let
        counter :: Behavior t Int
        counter = accumB 0 $ ((+1) <$ eup) `union` (subtract 1 <$ edown)

    sink output [text :== show <$> counter]

network <- compile networkDescription
actuate network
```

how can I replace and update the `Int` counter with a more generic `data` like:

```hs
data Counter = Counter {
     count :: Int
 } deriving (Show)

let
    counter :: Behavior t Counter
    counter = accumB Counter { count = 0 } $ ??????

sink output [text :== show <$> count counter]
```

I don't know how to refer to the internal `count` function with something like this:

```hs
count = count mycounter + 1
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `accumB` is:

```
accumB :: a -> Event t (a -> a) -> Behavior t a
```

So if you want to define a `Behavior t Counter` with it you need to use events that carry `Counter -> Counter` functions:

```
-- For the sake of convenience...
overCount :: (Int -> Int) -> Counter -> Counter
overCount f c = c { count = f (count c) }
```

```
counter = accumB Counter { count = 0 } $
    (overCount (+1) <$ eup) `union` (overCount (subtract 1) <$ edown)
```